# how to install wine 4.6 on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: wine, 19.04

this shouldn't be very hard but I've had no success...i found a few sites and copied few command lines into terminal and i can't get wine on Ubuntu 19.04. can someone drop some command lines for me so i can get wine 4.0 or 4.6 or 4.7 on my 19.04 laptop??

Comment: Why don't you install it from the repository? Like using the Ubuntu Software tool?

Comment: when i go into the software store and search wine...nothing comes up

Comment: Follow the answer below.

Comment: @TianJin Wine is like a background application without a well presented front-end. In Software centre you'll usually find GUI applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wine 4 is available in official repository of Disco Dingo. Just do:

```
sudo apt install wine
```

Comment: will try this tonight...i've seen people say you have to grab the winekey and this and that...

Comment: @TianJin winekey is required when you are using wine's repository to install.

Comment: ok so i have wine 4.0 according to Terminal but when I try to wine config...nothing happens. look at this error msg.

Comment: sailortian@sailortian-Satellite-P755:~$ wine --version
wine-4.0 (Ubuntu 4.0-1)
sailortian@sailortian-Satellite-P755:~$ winecfg
0009:err:file:init_redirects cannot open L"C:\\windows" (c000000f)
0009:err:process:init_windows_dirs directory L"C:\\windows" could not be created, error 2

Comment: why is this going to L "C:\\windows" that don't look right

Comment: @TianJin, Do you have write permissions in that place? Ask another question, if you could not solve the problem.

Comment: you know what...after looking into my "wine" folder...i took out the virtue C drive and put it on my "desktop" i believe i need a virtue C drive folder within Wine folder. am i right??

Comment: @TianJin, yes. You need virtual C drive folder inside wine folder to run programs. In default mode, you can find it under ~/.wine folder.